# Form Post 2 places altering field names in second submit

Tags: javascript, java, php, forms, curl

Here is the code that I am using. It submits fine the way it is to the two places I need it to. What I need to accomplish is this:

Submit the form as is to the first post location. That's obviously no problem, lol. Here's the rub.... I would like to amend the form field names that is submitted to the second post location.

Example: Field name is: "Administrator". When posting to the second post location place something like: "Some_Text_Administrator"

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance to this fine community!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Register</title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script type='text/javascript' src='gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
</head>
<body onload='hideResultDiv();'>


<div id='allcontainer'>
<div id='formcontainer'>
<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='' method='post' class="xxxx" name="xxxx">

<fieldset >
<legend>Title Here</legend>


<tr>
      <td>
<font size=2 face=arial color=#333333>
              <b>Account Administrator</b>
            </font>
</td>
<td>
<input type=text size=40 name=Administrator>
</td>
</tr> 


<tr>
      <td>
<font size=2 face=arial color=#333333>
              <b>Administrator Email</b>
            </font>
</td>
<td>
<input type=text size=40 name=email>
</td>
</tr> 




<tr>
      <td>
<font size=2 face=arial color=#333333>
              <b>State</b>
            </font>
</td>
<td>
<select name=State_Location1>
<option></option>
<option>AL</option>
<option>AK</option>
<option>AZ</option>
<option>AR</option>
<option>CA</option>
<option>CO</option>
<option>CT</option>
<option>DC</option>
<option>DE</option>
<option>FL</option>
<option>GA</option>
<option>HI</option>
<option>ID</option>
<option>IL</option>
<option>IN</option>
<option>IA</option>
<option>KS</option>
<option>KY</option>
<option>LA</option>
<option>ME</option>
<option>MD</option>
<option>MA</option>
<option>MI</option>
<option>MN</option>
<option>MS</option>
<option>MO</option>
<option>MT</option>
<option>NE</option>
<option>NV</option>
<option>NH</option>
<option>NJ</option>
<option>NM</option>
<option>NY</option>
<option>NC</option>
<option>ND</option>
<option>OH</option>
<option>OK</option>
<option>OR</option>
<option>PA</option>
<option>RI</option>
<option>SC</option>
<option>SD</option>
<option>TN</option>
<option>TX</option>
<option>UT</option>
<option>VT</option>
<option>VA</option>
<option>WA</option>
<option>WV</option>
<option>WI</option>
<option>WY</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr> 

<tr>
      <td>
<font size=2 face=arial color=#333333>
              <b>Zip Code</b>
            </font>
</td>
<td>
<input type=text size=20 name=Zip_Code_Location1>
</td>
</tr> 


<tr>
      <td>
<font size=2 face=arial color=#333333>
              Category 1
            </font>
</td>
<td>
<select name=Category1>
<option></option>
<option>Cat 1</option>
<option>Cat 2</option>
<option>Cat 3</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr> 
</table>



<div class='container'>
    <input type='button' name='Submit' value='Submit' onclick='javascript: return SubmitForm()' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactus");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please provide a valid email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("message","maxlen=2048","The message is too long!(more than 2KB!)");
// ]]>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function SubmitForm()
{
    if(document.forms['contactus'].onsubmit())
    {
        showResultDiv();
        document.forms['contactus'].action='xxxx1';
        document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result1';
        document.forms['contactus'].submit();

        document.forms['contactus'].action='xxxx2';
        document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result2';
        document.forms['contactus'].submit();
    }
    return true;
}

function showResultDiv()
{
    var result_div = document.getElementById('resultcontainer');
    result_div.style.display="";
}

function hideResultDiv()
{
    var result_div = document.getElementById('resultcontainer');
    result_div.style.display='none';
}


</script>
<!--
Form Code End
-->
</div >
<div id='resultcontainer'>
There are three iframes below, that
shows results from each of the action scripts.

<div class='iframe_container'>
<iframe name='frame_result1' width='400px' height='400px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
<div class='iframe_container'>
<iframe name='frame_result2' width='400px' height='400px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</div>
</div >
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to name a input dynamically? You want that the user inputted information in one input becomes the name of another input?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Yes, I believe so. The input of the first is "Administrator" for example. The input of the second submit will also be Administrator, but amended to be "Second_Name_Administrator", for example. The "Second_Name_" would be added to all the fields names, not just Administrator. So, Administrator, Account, etc. would be "Second_Name_Administrator", "Second_Name_Account", etc.

Comment: Ok, but that Second_Name is the user that writes? Suppose i'am your user, then i write "leoap" in the Administrator field and submit. the next form input will be "leoap_Administrator"?

Comment: No, the "answer" would be simply leoap. The "field name" is what I need to change when submitting to the second post location. Sorry, I more than likely did not explain myself well enough.  The two places the form submits to requires that the "field name" be slightly different. InfusionSoft is the second Post location and they put the "Second_Name_" part in their forms and there is no way around that. So, instead of re-writing the entire database for post location 1, I was hoping to simply (simply... haha) amend the already made form that submits to location 1 with the amended field names.

Comment: Form for Location 1: <input type=text size=40 name=Administrator> when submitting to Location 2 it needs to be: <input type=text size=40  name=Second_Name_Administrator>

Comment: Oh now i understood. Have you some of way to identify that the user is in location 2? if so, just create your input as: `<input type=text size=40 name=<?php if($location == 2){ echo "Second_Name_"; } ?>Administrator>`

Comment: First, thank you very much for helping! Actually, there is only one form, but it submits to two places at once using JavaScript to perform the onsubmit function (See JavaScript towards the bottom of the above code).  But I think you are on to something...  Wondering if your method might be hacked into my duel submit function to make the second onsubmit place the needed "Second_Name_" in front of every field? Goodness... hope that made sense, haha.

Comment: By the way, I'm not new to this site, but very new to actually posting questions, How do I give you credit for helping me thus far?

Comment: "document.forms['contactus'].action='xxxx1';" and - "document.forms['contactus'].action='xxxx2'; " in the code above BTW.

Comment: you cant gimme credit as i am just using the comments to ask for clarification of your question. don't worry with that. You should then change de name of your inputs using Javascript AFTER submitting to first location. I will make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to add an `id` to the inputs that you want the name changed. That will make your life easier when selecting those inputs.

So, the first input will be: `<input id="input_administrator" type="text" size="40" name="Administrator">`

Then, in your function that does the submission, after the first submit, you just change the name of the inputs, getting then by their id and changing their name attribute:

```
function SubmitForm()
{
    if(document.forms['contactus'].onsubmit())
    {
        showResultDiv();
        document.forms['contactus'].action='xxxx1';
        document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result1';
        document.forms['contactus'].submit();

        // Changing the name of the inputs, to submit to location 2
        document.getElementById("input_administrator").name = "Second_Name_Administrator";

        document.forms['contactus'].action='xxxx2';
        document.forms['contactus'].target='frame_result2';
        document.forms['contactus'].submit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this example I've used only the input Administrator, you should do it for every input

Comment: Oh wow... I get it! Thank you kindly. I cannot input your code at the moment but I will in the next few hours. I'll let you know how it goes :-) Of course I'll mark it as answered and give full credit. Thanks again!